# 3 select elements that change options based on the selected option in the first and second select

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, drop-down-menu

The title maybe a little confusing but here we go in details.
So i have 3 dropdown-lists. The options in the second 'select' element have to be unique, based on the selected option in the first 'select' selected option.
Same thing with the third one, it should have unique options based on the selected option in the second 'select' selected option.

As far as i have gone, i am able to change the second 'select' options based on what i select on the first 'select', but when i change the second 'select' option, the third 'select' options dont change at all.
Here is the HTML:

```
<select id="item1">
<option value="0">1 item</option>
<option value="1">2 item</option>
<option value="2">3 item</option>
</select>

<select id="item2">
<option value="">-- select one -- </option>
</select>

<select id="item3">
<option> -- select another one --</option>
</select>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$("#item1, #item2").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("#item2").html(options[value]);

    var value1 =$("#item2").val();
    $("item3").html(options[value]);
});


var options = [
    "<option value='test'>item1: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item1: test 2</option>",
    "<option value='test'>item2: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item2: test 2</option>",
    "<option value='test'>item3: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item3: test 2</option>"
];


var options1 = ["<option value='test'>item33313: test 3332233</option>
<option value='test3'>item333: test 33333</option>","<option 
value='test'>item33313: tesdadadadadat 3332233</option><option 
value='test3'>item333: test 33333</option>","<option 
value='test'>itlolooloem33313: test 3332233</option><option 
value='test3'>item333: ltoltrolltest 33333</option>"];
```

});
And here is the JSfiddle:
    http://jsfiddle.net/2hyda4b1/
Any help/tip is appreciated a lot!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are passing the value to the next drop down you are passing the index from dropdown 1 to dropdown 2, from dropdown 2 to dropdown 3 you're passing the value.
drop down one you select first option
The value passed to the second drop down is 1.
The value you select drop down two is 1
The value you pass is test1

The values you are using in drop down 2 are dependent or pointing to the values of drop down one.  You should decouple this, specifically pass the index or value to set the options array.

Something like so:
`
$(document).ready(function() {

```
$("#item1").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("#item2").html(options[value]);
});

$("#item2").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("#item3").html(options[value]);
});


var options = [
    "<option value='0'>item1: test 1</option><option value='1'>item1: test 2</option>",
    "<option value='0'>item2: test 1</option><option value='1'>item2: test 2</option>",
    "<option value='0'>item3: test 1</option><option value='1'>item3: test 2</option>"
];
```

});
`

Comment: i tried this method you described but it is not working. thank you for the input tho...

Comment: Curious than because it works in the same Fiddle that you sent.  My target here was to trigger the drop down to populate with values based on selection for the second drop down.  I think you may need to further clarify what you want the third drop down to do.  As I am satisfying your question, the third drop is changing with the change to your second drop down.

Comment: I can see that it changes. maybe i was not clear enough.

they actually change but, i need each option of the second select to have different sub options, different from the others.
basically, what i need irl is a select list where i can choose the City.Depending on the City, i need to populate the second select element with the Hospitals available in that city(which obviously are different from the hospitals in another city),and after i choose the hospital, i need to populate a third select element with the services available based on the chosen hospital.

Comment: **UPDATE**
i need to choose multiple services on the third select element, and i thought to use a plugin,
but showing/hiding a div with checkboxes inside is good to go too, thank you

Comment: To do so, then you'd follow the same logic I post in my answer.  Each drop down is Unique, even though they are depend on the latter.  So if you're selecting say State = NY you pass an ID/Selected Index or some value that indicates that it is New York so your grouping in the second drop down then shows the Cities for New York.  And the same goes for the Hospitals per city in NY. The code is correct, it's about how you use the data to populate the groupings.

Comment: Three Groups: STATE, CITIES, HOSPTIALS.
STATE: Passes group id to populate CITIES
CITIES: Passes Group ID to populate HOSPITALS
All of this is done on drop down selected index change

Comment: I managed to achieve what i needed, but i wrote my own code.
the code consists on selected index of the first dropdown(city)
based on the city, it shows the hopsitals for each city. to populate a third dropdown, i used the condition if(hopsitalname=="hospitalName Example"){show div}
and i had to do a lot of IF conditions. if you are interested, i can show you an example.

Comment: If it works and you're happy no need to show me I believe you.  I hate writing a ton of if statements back to back.  I wonder if you could use recursion to simplify it?  Either way good luck to you.  Keep coding!